# I am trying to scroll handson table using selenium web driver but unable to do so

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My handson table has 200+ records. but I can only see first 27 records and only first 8 columns out of 25 columns.

Following are type of code I have tried.

1. Code 1:

   ```
   WebElement invoice=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ht_aeb2df21163d7999']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/a/i"));
   int y=invoice.getLocation().y; 
   int x=invoice.getLocation().x; 
   Actions act=new Actions(driver); 
   act.clickAndHold(invoice).dragAndDropBy(invoice,x,y).build().perform();
   invoice.click();
   ```
2. Code 2:

   ```
   Actions action=new Actions(driver);
   action.sendKeys(Keys.LEFT).perform();
   action.sendKeys(Keys.LEFT).perform();
   action.sendKeys(Keys.LEFT).perform();
   ```
3. Code 3:

   ```
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   js.executeScript("scroll(0, 750)");
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to receive the url with the table?

Comment: It's not possible to give you a URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the javascript method but target the actual element to scroll. The `scroll` function targets the window.

For example, I can scroll the [example here](http://handsontable.com/examples.html#fndtn-basic) by executing

```
document.querySelectorAll('.wtHolder')[0].scrollTop = 500
```

with the dev tools console.